# Question regarding notation for F-distribution

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, notation

Apologies for the basic question; I don't have a very deep or broad background in statistics.

I am reading [this paper on phase transitions in the existence of maximum likelihood estimators for logistic regression](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09753.pdf). On page 4, Section 2.1, (The Main Result), it is written:

$(Y,V) \sim  F_{\beta_\theta \gamma _\theta}$ if $(Y,V) \equiv (Y,YX)$

I don't quite understand this notation (for the first part). My understanding  is that

$X \sim D(\alpha_1,\alpha_2...)$ means that the random variable X has a distribution D that depends on the parameters alpha.

In this case, the F distribution really does exist and generally is written with two parameters: [F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution). A ratio of two Chi distributed variables normalised by the number of their degrees of freedom. It can also be written as a ratio of normalised normal-distributed variables.

I initially interpreted the statement as meaning 'Y and V are drawn from the same F distribution, characterised by the parameters $\beta_\theta , \gamma_\theta$. However, this can't be right. Y is a Bernoulli random variable (on page 5 in the effective case of $\beta=0$, "Y is a Rademacher variable".

Could someone please help me to understand this notation?

Comment: When the paper refers to the distribution $F$, they don't mean the Snedecor-[F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_distribution). It represents a distribution that fits whatever the conditions are ("some distribution $F$", as the paper puts it). Further note that the F distribution cannot actually be "written as a ratio of normalised normal-distributed variables". I presume you mean something else. A ratio of standardized normals would be Cauchy, not F.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for your reply. I see I did read the Wiki page on F distribution too quickly- it is written as a ratio of normalised sum of squares for normal distributed vairables, i.e. chi square distribution. I was wondering, presumably this notation DOES necessarily imply that Y and V are drawn from the same distribution? And yet Y takes on only 2 values and V is multinormal?

Comment: ... I don't see anything that would suggest Y and V are drawn from the same distribution. What made you think so?

Comment: @Glen_b That they are written as ~F for both of them. If they are from different disrributions, having different dependencies on the parameters, I would have thought it better to write Y~F1_(beta, gamma), V~F2_(beta, gamma), unless the notation with F is standard and simply meaning "a distribution depending on these parameters, but the elements from the tuple need not be from the same distribution F". I just cannot think if another area of mathematics where the notation given wouldn't mean that Y/V belong to the same set/object/drawn from same distribution. For suppose then that they were

Comment: drawn from the same unknown distribution. How would this be written?

Comment: Ah! I understand your confusion. F is the *joint* distribution of Y and V, but in general each of the marginal distributions needn't be of the same form. For example we may well have Y~S and V~T for some distributions S and T.